# distinct grouped by results with a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case, case-statement

[image]

I couldn't really come up with a good title for this.
I have data in the first picture.
If the person has either Blue or green, I want the query to return in one row the Person as one column and then "Yes" in the second column (I can do that step with a case statement).
If the person has all other colors, I want it to return the person's name and "No" in the second column.
The Group By is important because I just want the people to appear once with a "yes" in the second column if they have any blue or green or a "no" if they don't.

[How the results should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex4J7.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, but since you seem to want to use a GROUP BY and CASE, what you can do is get the MAX of a CASE when the color is blue or green THEN 1, ELSE 0.

That will give you each name with either a 1 or 0, and then you can use either another CASE or REPLACE to change 1 to "yes" and 0 to "no".

Another approach that might be more efficient and easy to read/maintain would be do select the DISTINCT names, and do a CASE WHEN EXISTS() with a correlated sub-query that checks to see if any record exists with that name and either blue or green.   WHEN EXISTS(...) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reponse, Tab!

I don't need a group by and a case statement if there are more efficient routes to take!

I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

See below approach using `common table expression`. This returns the expected result

```
;WITH YES_RES AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PERSON, 'YES' AS RES FROM tabname
    WHERE COLOR IN ('Blue', 'Green')
),
NO_RES AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PERSON, 'NO' AS RES FROM tabname
    WHERE PERSON NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PERSON FROM YES_RES)
)
SELECT PERSON, RES FROM YES_RES
UNION
SELECT PERSON, RES FROM NO_RES
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select person,
       (case when sum(case when color in ('blue', 'green') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as flag
from t
group by person
```